# import text by javascript function

Tags: javascript, text, quotes

I am using this code to import text from js file to html but it's not work, i don't know what is the problem.

```js
const quotes = [{
    "quote": "This is just a Quote1",
    "source": "Christopher"
  },
  {
    "quote": "This is just a Quote2",
    "source": "Martin"
  },
  {
    "quote": "This is just a Quote3",
    "source": "Dennis"
  },
]

function randomQuote() {
  let random = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
  quotation.innerText = `"${random.quote}"`;
  source.innerText = random.source;
}

randomQuote();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="trivia/quotes.js"></script>

<blockquote>
  <p id="quotation"></p>
  <footer>
    <p id="source"></p>
  </footer>
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the variables `quotation` and `source`:

```js
const quotes = [{
    "quote": "This is just a Quote1",
    "source": "Christopher"
  },
  {
    "quote": "This is just a Quote2",
    "source": "Martin"
  },
  {
    "quote": "This is just a Quote3",
    "source": "Dennis"
  },
]

var quotation = document.getElementById('quotation'); // get the quotation <p>
var source = document.getElementById('source'); // get the source <p>

function randomQuote() {
  let random = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
  quotation.innerText = `"${random.quote}"`;
  source.innerText = random.source;
}

randomQuote();
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <p id="quotation"></p>
  <footer>
    <p id="source"></p>
  </footer>
</blockquote>
```